# React Native pass index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making a music app using [react-native-track-player](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player). I made 3 components called `Clusters`, `Songlist` and `Play`.

**How screen works**

`Clusters` component -> `Songlist` component -> `Play` component. Problem for me is that I don't know how to pass the index of the song selected to the `SongList` component from `Clusters` component which will also allow me to pass it to my `Play` component. I am not sure how to do it.

I created data. First screen shows title and mood(`Songlist` component). Second screen (`Songlist` shows the playlist depending on the title that I clicked.

This is my where I get my `data` in another file

```
const ClusterData = [
  {
    title: "Cluster1",
    data: [
      { name: "passionate" },
      { name: "rousing" },
      { name: "confident" },
      { name: "boisterous" },
      { name: "rowdy" }
    ],
    songlist: [
      {
        id: "2222",
        url: "http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Post_Malone_-_Better_Now.mp3",
        title: "Better Now",
        artist: "Post Malone"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        url:
          "http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/5_Seconds_Of_Summer_-_Youngblood.mp3",
        title: "YoungBlood",
        artist: "5SOS"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Cluster2",
    data: [
      { name: "rollicking" },
      { name: "cheerful" },
      { name: "fun" },
      { name: "sweet" },
      { name: "amiable" },
      { name: "natured" }
    ],
    songlist: [
      {
        id: "1111",
        url:
          "http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Yellow_Claw_and_San_Holo_-_Summertime.mp3",
        title: "Summertime",
        artist: "Yellow Claw"
      },
      {
        id: "1",
        url:
          "http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Luis_Fonsi_feat._Daddy_Yankee_-_Despacito.mp3",
        title: "Despacito",
        artist: "Luis Fonsi"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This is my `Clusters` screen (first screen)

```
export default class Clusters extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            return (
              <SectionListItem item={item} index={index}>
                {" "}
              </SectionListItem>
            );
          }}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
            return <SectionHeader section={section} />;
          }}
          sections={ClusterData}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class SectionHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headertext}>{this.props.section.title}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => Actions.SongList({ section: this.props.section })}
        >
          <Text style={styles.Play}> Play</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SectionListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.moodname}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my `SongList` screen (second screen)

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.section.songlist}
          renderItem={({ item, index, rowId }) => {
            return <FlatListItem item={item} index={index} />;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class FlatListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            Actions.Play({
              songlist: this.props.item.songlist,
              item: this.props.item
            })
          }
        >
          <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{this.props.item.songtitle}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemArtist}>{this.props.item.artist}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my `Play` screen

```
import TrackPlayer from "react-native-track-player";

export default class Play extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(async () => {
      // Adds a track to the queue
      await TrackPlayer.add(this.props.item.songlist[index]);
      // Starts playing it
      TrackPlayer.play();
    });
  }
  onPressPlay = () => {
    TrackPlayer.play();
  };
  onPressPause = () => {
    TrackPlayer.pause();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.play} onPress={this.onPressPlay}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: "bold",
                textAlign: "center",
                color: "white"
              }}
            >
              Play
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.pause} onPress={this.onPressPause}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: "bold",
                textAlign: "center",
                color: "white"
              }}
            >
              Pause
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just try passing a function as a prop that you can call in the child

```
function setSong(var selectedSong){
 // do something with the selectedsong, maybe in the state
  this.setState({currentSong: selectedSong});
}
```

and then pass this function

```
 <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            Actions.Play({
              songlist: this.props.item.songlist,
              item: this.props.item,
              setSong: () => this.setSong 
            })
          }
        >
```

Comment: Where do I place the private function?

Comment: You should ignore the **private** this is for Typescript I suppose

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class App extends Component { 

 setSong(var selectedSong){
 // do something with the selectedsong, maybe in the state
  this.setState({currentSong: selectedSong});
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.section.songlist}
          renderItem={({ item, index, rowId }) => {
            return <FlatListItem item={item} index={index} />;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So I need to add somethin in the //do something with the selectedsong?

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new

Comment: In that function you work the data that comes in. I would make a a value in de state that is called index and  i would pass that value so this.state.index to my child components. and in the function i would do newSongItem then check the list of songs to get the index then to setState the index to safe it in de state and by the setstate the render is called and the new index is passed to the child component.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
    export default class App extends Component {
     this.state = {
        index:0
      }
   setSong(var selectedSong){
     var index = this.props.songlist.index(selectedSong);
     this.setState({index: index}); 
   }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.section.songlist}
          renderItem={({ item, index, rowId }) => {
            return <FlatListItem item={item} index={index} />;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class FlatListItem extends Component {
  this.state = {
        index:0
      }
   setSong(var selectedSong){
     var index = this.props.songlist.index(selectedSong);
     this.setState({index: index}); 
   }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            Actions.Play({
              songlist: this.props.item.songlist,
              item: this.props.item,
              index: this.state.index,
              setSong: () => this.setSong  
            })
          }
        >
          <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{this.props.item.songtitle}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemArtist}>{this.props.item.artist}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't work. They said there is an unexpected token. A constructor,method, accessor, or property was expected. There error is in this statement this.state = {
       index:0
     }
  setSong(var selectedSong){
    var index = this.props.songlist.index(selectedSong);
    this.setState({index: index}); 
  }